# How do i clear a specific cell with VBA

Tags: vba

I can't finish the last part of my code if anyone could assist. When a cell is not a number I need it to delete the data in the cell.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Please edit your question and `copy/paste` the code *here*.

Comment: Maybe if you change `.ClearContents` to `Cells(10 + x, 9).Value = ""`?

Comment: @Libby1234  have you tried any of the answers below ? any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Sub ValueOnly()

Dim x As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Consolidated Data")
    For x = 1 To 3107

        With .Cells(10 + x, 9)
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then .ClearContents
        End With

        With .Cells(10 + x, 10)
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then .ClearContents
        End With

    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

since `IsNumeric()` can have issues, you may want to try a `SpecialCells()` approach, which is a little trickier:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ValueOnly()
    Dim numericRng As Range, lastNumericRng As Range, lastRng As Range
    Dim iArea As Long

    With Sheets("Consolidated Data").Range("I11:I3317").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| consider only your wanted range "not blank" values
        Set numericRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| store "numeric" values

        If Intersect(.Cells(1), numericRng) Is Nothing Then '<--| check if first value is not numeric
            .Parent.Range(.Cells(1), numericRng(1).Offset(-1)).ClearContents
        End If

        With numericRng
            For iArea = 2 To .areas.Count '<--| clear all not numeric values between numeric ones
                .Parent.Range(.areas(iArea - 1).Offset(.areas(iArea - 1).Count).Resize(1), _
                              .areas(iArea).Resize(1).Offset(-1)).ClearContents
            Next
        End With

        Set lastRng = .areas(.areas.Count).Cells(.areas(.areas.Count).Count)
        If Intersect(lastRng, numericRng) Is Nothing Then '<--| check if last value is not numeric
            With numericRng
                Set lastNumericRng = .areas(.areas.Count).Offset(.areas(.areas.Count).Count).Resize(1)
            End With
            .Parent.Range(lastNumericRng, lastRng).ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```